WPF - Binding a Listview as a sub element of rowdetailstemplate
I need to understand how I can bind a listview inside a RowDetailsTemplate.
this is my XAML:
<Window x:Class="TestWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="TestDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Binding="{Binding Code}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="15" Margin="10">
                        <Grid Margin="5">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock  Text="CurrentStyle: "/>
                                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Cstyle}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <TextBlock  Text="Available Styles"/>
                                <ListView x:Name="styleList" Height="135" >
                                    <GridView>
                                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding sCode}" Header="Name"/>
                                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding sColor}" Header="Color"/>
                                    </GridView>
                                </ListView>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>

and this is my code-behind:
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace TestWPF
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logica di interazione per MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public List<GridElement> GridList { get; set; }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            GridList = new List<GridElement>
            {
                new GridElement
                {
                    Code = "ABC",
                    Description = "Description for ABC",
                    Cstyle = "Current style ABC",
                    AvailableStyles = new List<Styles> { new Styles() { sCode = "Styletest1-ABC", sColor = "blue" },
                    new Styles() { sCode = "Styletest2-ABC", sColor = "red" }

                }
                },
                new GridElement
                {
                    Code = "DEF",
                    Description = "Description for DEF",
                    Cstyle = "Current style DEF",
                    AvailableStyles = new List<Styles> { new Styles() { sCode = "Styletest1-DEF", sColor = "white" },
                    new Styles() { sCode = "Styletest2-ABC", sColor = "black" }

                }
                }
            };

            TestDataGrid.ItemsSource = this.GridList;
        }
    }

    public class GridElement
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Cstyle { get; set; }
       

        public List<Styles> AvailableStyles { get; set; }
    }

    public class Styles
    {
        public string sCode { get; set; }
        public string sColor { get; set; }

    }
}

but the result is the one in the image.
This is the result
What I need is that the listview in the rowdetail changes according to the row of the main grid I choose.
So if i clicked on the first line, I will see the styles for ABC listed in the listview (I.E. the color, but it's not important what to display), and  the same if I click on the second line.
Thank you for your help
SOLUTION
I report the solution I found for my issue, just for information:
<ListView x:Name="styleList" Height="135" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableStyles}" >
                            <ListView.View>
                                <GridView>
                                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding sCode}" Header="Name"/>
                                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding sColor}" Header="Color"/>
                                </GridView>
                                </ListView.View>
                            </ListView>


Your ListView miss the ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableStyles}" argument. Therefore, the ListView doesn't know where to find the sColor and sCode arguments.

And I also think you miss the this.DataContext = this; in the MainWindow() function to allow data binding

Hello Maxime, thank you for your help. If I try to add the binding to the listview, I receive an exception when I click on a row. Do I need to use an observablecollection in place of the Availablestyle list?

an observablecollection instead of a List is only usefull if you modify the Availablestyle List dynamically (add/edit/remove items from the list in the background). i don't think your exception comes from that

I don't neet to change the elements in the grid, so I don't need an observable collection.The exception say: Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead

Finally I found what's wrong with my XAML, I miss the <ListView.View> enclosing the !

Your code is nearly perfect. However this happens because the ItemsSource property of the ListView is not set, and the ListView.View element is missing. Here’s how you can address and resolve this issue.
Binding the ItemsSource Property
The ItemsSource property is essential for populating the ListView with data. In your case, you want the ListView to display the AvailableStyles for each GridElement. By binding the ItemsSource of the ListView to the AvailableStyles property, you ensure that the correct data is displayed for each row.
By setting ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableStyles}", you are telling the ListView to use the AvailableStyles collection from the current GridElement as its data source. Without this, the ListView has no data to display.
Defining the ListView.View
The ListView.View property is necessary to define the layout and columns of the data you want to display in the ListView. In this case, a GridView is used to define columns for sCode and sColor.
The ListView.View element, specifically a GridView, defines how each item in the ListView is displayed. It specifies that each item should be displayed with two columns: one for sCode and one for sColor. Without this, the ListView would not know how to render the data.
Final result
You final WPF will looks like that:
<ListView x:Name="styleList" Height="135" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableStyles}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding sCode}" Header="Name"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding sColor}" Header="Color"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>

And the app like that:

I hope this helps! If you have any further questions, feel free to ask.

It's perfect now. thank you again for your help!
